# Creating new version of journey - Contact Entry in journey settings won't let me choose anything other than "No Re-Entry"

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

This may be a really simple question, but I can't seem to figure this one out. I created a new version of a journey I created, as i noticed I incorrectly selected "No Re-Entry" on the previous version. On the new version that has yet to be activated, when I try and select "re-entry only after exiting", i get a red circle with a line through it where my pointer would normally be. Clearly, MC is telling me this option is not available.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to why this is occurring? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this help doc: [Journey settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5)

> Select No re-entry if contacts can’t enter the journey again after a previous entry. For example, in a Welcome Journey, set your entry to No re-entry because you want your customers to be introduced to your brand only one time. This setting applies across all versions of a journey. After you activate the journey, you can’t change this option.

You will need to copy this journey to change the re-entry settings